# biblatex-chicago, alphabetical bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, chicago-style

I'm using biblatex-chicago, and the bibliography is being sorted by order of citation instead of alphabetically. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had files from v0.9 and v1.2 floating around, which made things unhappy. Replacing the v0.9 file with the v1.2 file made it work again.

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage[...,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
```

where `nyt` sorts by "name year title" should work... There several more options (like `nty`) to be found in the biblatex manual on page 43.

Comment: It didn't work ... I'm not sure why. Any other ideas?